# Deserialize a json file with json.net with int values on structure

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

Can someone help me to deserialize this JSON file?

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "records": {
    "504498959": {
      "nif": 504498959,
      "seo_url": "triworld-equipamentos-informaticos-e-de-telecomunicacoes-unipessoal-lda",
      "title": "Triworld - Equipamentos Inform\u00e1ticos e de Telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es, Unipessoal Lda",
      "address": "Rua Doutor Francisco Noronha, N 31",
      "pc4": "4700",
      "pc3": "355",
      "city": "Braga",
      "activity": "O com\u00e9rcio, importa\u00e7\u00f5es, exporta\u00e7\u00f5es e representa\u00e7\u00f5es de material e equipamento inform\u00e1tico, de telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es; montagem, instala\u00e7\u00e3o, assist\u00eancia t\u00e9cnica, desenvolvimento de programas inform\u00e1ticos e outros similares.",
      "status": "active",
      "cae": "47781",
      "contacts": {
        "email": null,
        "phone": "253261844",
        "website": null,
        "fax": "253613646"
      },
      "structure": {
        "nature": "UNI",
        "capital": "0.00",
        "capital_currency": "EUR"
      },
      "geo": {
        "region": "Braga",
        "county": "Braga",
        "parish": "S\u00e3o Vicente"
      },
      "place": {
        "address": "Rua Doutor Francisco Noronha, N 31",
        "pc4": "4700",
        "pc3": "355",
        "city": "Braga"
      },
      "racius": "http:\/\/www.racius.com\/triworld-equipamentos-informaticos-e-de-telecomunicacoes-unipessoal-lda\/",
      "alias": "Triworld - Equip. Informaticos e de Telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es,unipes., Lda",
      "portugalio": "http:\/\/www.portugalio.com\/triworld-equip-informaticos-e-de-telecomunicacoes-unipes\/"
    }
  },
  "nif_validation": true,
  "is_nif": true,
  "credits": {
    "used": "Triworld - Equipamentos Informáticos e de Telecomunicações, Unipessoal Lda",
    "left": {
      "month": 993,
      "day": 99,
      "hour": 9,
      "minute": 0,
      "paid": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Rootobject
{
    public string result { get; set; }
    public Records records { get; set; }
    public bool nif_validation { get; set; }
    public bool is_nif { get; set; }
    public Credits credits { get; set; }
}

public class Records
{
    public _504498959 _504498959 { get; set; }
}

public class _504498959
{
    public int nif { get; set; }
    public string seo_url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string pc4 { get; set; }
    public string pc3 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string activity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string cae { get; set; }
    public Contacts contacts { get; set; }
    public Structure structure { get; set; }
    public Geo geo { get; set; }
    public Place place { get; set; }
    public string racius { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string portugalio { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    public object email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public object website { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
}

public class Structure
{
    public string nature { get; set; }
    public string capital { get; set; }
    public string capital_currency { get; set; }
}

public class Geo
{
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string county { get; set; }
    public string parish { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string pc4 { get; set; }
    public string pc3 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}

public class Credits
{
    public string used { get; set; }
    public Left left { get; set; }
}

public class Left
{
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int hour { get; set; }
    public int minute { get; set; }
    public int paid { get; set; }
}




protected void VerificaNif(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Rootobject jsonfileroot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(get_web_content("http://www.triworld.pt/4FPIL83K.json"));

    // need to use "records": { "504498959": { "title": "Triworld - Equipamentos Inform\u00e1ticos e de Telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es, Unipessoal Lda", on a textbox named Nome.Text

    if (jsonfileroot.result == "success")
    {
        Nome.Text = jsonfileroot.records._504498959.title;
    }
    else
    {
        erro.Text = " Nif is Invalid";
    }
}
```

but it gives me an `NullReferenceException`, it can not reach the title.

Could someone help me please? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here's a working .NetFiddle. It should auto-run. Otherwise just click <kbd>RUN</kbd> on that page. See the console output below on that page.

#### https://dotnetfiddle.net/rMA3Nt

#### Answer Details:

Change the declaration of your classes as shown below. Once you do that, the following code de-serializes correctly. Here's the output from my console app.

#### Console App output

[image]

#### Console App Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string theJson = "{ \"result\": \"success\", \"records\": { \"504498959\": { \"nif\": 504498959, \"seo_url\": \"triworld-equipamentos-informaticos-e-de-telecomunicacoes-unipessoal-lda\", \"title\": \"Triworld - Equipamentos Inform\u00e1ticos e de Telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es, Unipessoal Lda\", \"address\": \"Rua Doutor Francisco Noronha, N 31\", \"pc4\": \"4700\", \"pc3\": \"355\", \"city\": \"Braga\", \"activity\": \"O com\u00e9rcio, importa\u00e7\u00f5es, exporta\u00e7\u00f5es e representa\u00e7\u00f5es de material e equipamento inform\u00e1tico, de telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es; montagem, instala\u00e7\u00e3o, assist\u00eancia t\u00e9cnica, desenvolvimento de programas inform\u00e1ticos e outros similares.\", \"status\": \"active\", \"cae\": \"47781\", \"contacts\": { \"email\": null, \"phone\": \"253261844\", \"website\": null, \"fax\": \"253613646\" }, \"structure\": { \"nature\": \"UNI\", \"capital\": \"0.00\", \"capital_currency\": \"EUR\" }, \"geo\": { \"region\": \"Braga\", \"county\": \"Braga\", \"parish\": \"S\u00e3o Vicente\" }, \"place\": { \"address\": \"Rua Doutor Francisco Noronha, N 31\", \"pc4\": \"4700\", \"pc3\": \"355\", \"city\": \"Braga\" }, \"racius\": \"http://www.racius.com/triworld-equipamentos-informaticos-e-de-telecomunicacoes-unipessoal-lda/\", \"alias\": \"Triworld - Equip. Informaticos e de Telecomunica\u00e7\u00f5es,unipes., Lda\", \"portugalio\": \"http://www.portugalio.com/triworld-equip-informaticos-e-de-telecomunicacoes-unipes/\" } }, \"nif_validation\": true, \"is_nif\": true, \"credits\": { \"used\": \"Triworld - Equipamentos Informáticos e de Telecomunicações, Unipessoal Lda\", \"left\": { \"month\": 993, \"day\": 99, \"hour\": 9, \"minute\": 0, \"paid\": 0 } } }";
        Rootobject theRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(theJson);
        if (theRecords != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialization succeeded :)");
            if (theRecords.result == "success")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  # of Records: {0}", theRecords.records.Count);
                int recordCount = 1;
                foreach (var record in theRecords.records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    Record #{0}", recordCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("      Key: {0}", record.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine("        nif: {0}", record.Value.nif);
                    Console.WriteLine("        seo_url: {0}", record.Value.seo_url);
                    Console.WriteLine("        title: {0}", record.Value.title);
                    Console.WriteLine("        address: {0}", record.Value.address);
                    Console.WriteLine("        city: {0}", record.Value.city);
                    Console.WriteLine("        alias: {0}", record.Value.alias);
                    Console.WriteLine("        portugalio : {0}", record.Value.portugalio);
                    recordCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialization failed :(");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Here is how you need to modify your class declaration.

#### Console App Classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string result { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Location> records { get; set; }
    public bool nif_validation { get; set; }
    public bool is_nif { get; set; }
    public Credits credits { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int nif { get; set; }
    public string seo_url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string pc4 { get; set; }
    public string pc3 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string activity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string cae { get; set; }
    public Contacts contacts { get; set; }
    public Structure structure { get; set; }
    public Geo geo { get; set; }
    public Place place { get; set; }
    public string racius { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string portugalio { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    public object email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public object website { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
}

public class Structure
{
    public string nature { get; set; }
    public string capital { get; set; }
    public string capital_currency { get; set; }
}

public class Geo
{
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string county { get; set; }
    public string parish { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string pc4 { get; set; }
    public string pc3 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}

public class Credits
{
    public string used { get; set; }
    public Left left { get; set; }
}

public class Left
{
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int hour { get; set; }
    public int minute { get; set; }
    public int paid { get; set; }
}
```

#### Key Things To Note:

The `RootObject` has a `Dictionary<int, Location> records` that will have the `int` value as key and the object contained inside as a `Location` object.

If the `int` values could be duplicate in your final json, then change it to a `List<NameValuePair<string,Location>>`

The numeric key for the `records` entity will be the key of the `Dictionary` object inside the `RootObject`. The `value` will be the class called `Location` (I gave it that name, maybe something is more appropriate. You would know best.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it Works perfectly.

Comment: just can't reach on information below:

    public Contacts contacts { get; set; }
    public Structure structure { get; set; }
    public Geo geo { get; set; }
    public Place place { get; set; }

could you help me on that too?

Comment: Hi Filipe, I see the contact and geo objects are also populated (where they are not null of course). Are you not seeing it?

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks once again, the problem is that i was too tired to see that i was calling a null value, sorry to disturb, and thanks once again.